# Openpyxl doesn't support multi ranges for BarChart

Tags: excel, python-3.x, bar-chart, openpyxl

I need to create a XY Scatter plot in excel. I can do it manually but struggle in doing it in openpyxl.

For instance Series X values should look like:

> =(Sheet1!$Q$9:$Q$12, Sheet1!$Q$15:$Q$18)

Y series:

> =(Sheet1!$R$9:$R$12, Sheet1!$R$15:$R$18)

I'm trying to create a BarChart using openpyxl and as a type required is Reference, I can't assert several ranges in one Reference:

```
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

chart = BarChart()
chart.title = 'Title'
min_col, min_row, max_row = column_index_from_string('Q'), 9, 12
values = Reference(ws, min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row, max_row=max_row)
series = Series(values, title='series_title')
chart.append(series)  # the only series should be appended
```

What can I do? I can't create different series for each range because I need the only graph and a trendline after all.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with openpyxl.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Because the "Reference" type which can be set with one range of rows-columns only is demanded, but did someone edited library to add this feature?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I have already added some features to openpyxl redefining methods of classes which had less functionality that I needed. I mean if sth is missing in a library it's not the reason to leave it this way. So I asked this question to find out if someone has already faced this problem and come up with a solution. 
And anyway thank you for your replies.